ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt
I have a file encrypted from redhat with the script below.
---redhat script---
openssl enc -in $LOCAL_FILE -aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -pass file:${PASS} -out ${LOCAL_FILE}.tmp.$$

when I decrypted this file on window with openssl version3.3.1 and same pass file, it show erorr message as below.

bad decrypt
84210000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:..\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_block.c:107:

I think this error is because the password is incorrect.
Am I writing the script incorrectly? Or do I need to do something more if I use the same password as the file from redhat?
